# Add code to the getter of a property in lightswitch

Tags: c#, lightswitch-2013

Hello i'm new to microsoft lightswitch and i ran into a problem, i have a property that have to be able to get saved in the database so it can not be a computed property but i want to add an if statement to the getter of the property that in some condition it should not get the value from the database and it should return a computed value, does any one know how i can do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand but why not have the if statement determine if you use the getter. Have the computed value set to a variable and then return the variable. Again, i'm not the greatest but I hope I helped!